# Il n'y a d'original que le nom

Tags: grammaire

Qu'est-ce qu'il veut dire ici? Je ne le comprends pas. Il n'y a pas d'autres explications dans le livre.

Comment: De quel livre parle-tu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cette phrase porte un jugement à priori négatif sur quelque chose de banal à qui on a donné un nom inhabituel, inattendu, voire dont le nom lui-même contient l'adjectif original. Elle signifie:

> Seul le nom de ce dont on parle est original. En dehors de ça, c'est banal, éculé, conventionnel, il n'y a rien qui surprend.

Exemple d'utilisation :

> Dans la recette de la pomme de terre en robe des champs, il n'y a d'original que le nom.

Comment: Et régulièrement le terme "original" fait partie du nom. Ou tout autre terme employé ainsi

Answer (score 2):

Cette sorte de commentaire est souvent faite après une assertion ou une question qui implique l'originalité, soit avancée ou assertée soit hypothétique, d'un quelconque attribut d'une entité donnée (quelque chose ou quelqu'un) et elle est à l'effet du rejet de toute réalité quant à une originalité qui se rapporterait à cette entité, mis à part celle du nom. Cependant, même en ce qui concerne le nom il peut arriver que le jugement du locuteur ne soit pas des plus judicieux et que le nom ne soit pas des plus originaux.

"N'avoir d'original" est une construction plus courante qui ne dépend pas de ce qui a été dit pour son utilisation ([réf.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22n%27a+d%27original%22&safe=active&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixu6OQnIXtAhWIy4UKHX15AY0Q_AUICigA&biw=1600&bih=838&dpr=1.2)). Il ne faut pas confondre "*Il n'a d'original que le nom.*" avec "*Il n'y a d'original que le nom.*". Dans l'utilisation de cette première construction, ce qui est nié c'est la qualité qui correspond au nom. On dira sur ce modèle par exemple des phrases comme les suivantes.

- De gâteaux des rois il n'a que le nom.
- De vaches laitières elles n'ont que le nom, ce sont des animaux épuisés.
- De manteau d'hiver il n'a que le nom, on n'a pas plus chaud en le portant que si l'on avait une simple veste.
- L'idée de départ n'a d'original que le nom : une querelle de famille autour d'une maison après le décès du père. Et devinez quoi ? Il y a des ... ([réf.](https://www.lesechos.fr/2015/10/a-la-fin-de-lenvoi-touche-t-il-1108648))

Dans la première construction « original » est considéré en tant que nom grammatical alors que dans la seconde c'est en tant qu'adjectif qu'il est compris.

Comment: +1 pour les bons exemples. Dans un autre domaine et de manière même plus «objective» (quoique encore controversée dans certains cercles), on pourrait aussi penser à la nouvelle entité établie par l'Union astronomique internationale en 2006: une *planète naine* n'a de planète que le nom.

Answer (score 0):

*"Il n'y a de (ceci) que le nom"* signifie que, bien que la chose en question, généralement un ouvrage artistique ou littéraire, porte le qualificatif (ceci) dans son titre, elle ne mérite pas ce qualificatif.

Par exemple, un spectateur qui se serait ennuyé en voyant *"La Chevauchée Fantastique"* de John Ford, dirait : *"Ce film n'a de fantastique que le nom"*, sous-entendant par là que l'action de ce film n'a rien de fantastique à ses yeux.